# Target Sum does not output the right value

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to solve the target sum question (https://leetcode.com/problems/target-sum/description/)

```
You are given a list of non-negative integers,
a1, a2, ..., an, and a target, S. Now you have 2 symbols
+ and -. For each integer, you should choose one from
+ and - as its new symbol. Find out how many ways to assign symbols
to make sum of integers equal to target S
```

I was able to pass through basic cases but the case with (`[0,1], 1`) fails.

Trying to understand what am I doing wrong and how I can fix it.

```js
var findTargetSumWays = function(nums, total) {
    const res = [];
    let str = nums.join('');
    helper(str, '', 0);

    function helper(str, curStr, sum) {
        if(str.length===0) return;
        if(sum + Number(str) === total) {
            res.push(`${curStr}+${str}`);
            return;
        }

        if(sum - Number(str) === total) {
            res.push(`${curStr}-${str}`);
            return;
        }

        for(let i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
            helper(str.substring(i+1), `${curStr}+${str.substring(0, i+1)}`, sum+Number(str.substring(0, i+1)));
            helper(str.substring(i+1), `${curStr}-${str.substring(0, i+1)}`, sum-Number(str.substring(0, i+1)))
        }
    }
    
    return res.length; 
};
console.log(findTargetSumWays([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 3)); // Returns correct answer.
console.log(findTargetSumWays([1, 0], 1)); // Expected 2
```

Trying to figure out what's going wrong for the second input.

**My algorithm is/as follows:**

> 1) Convert the array to a string.
>
> 2) Do DFS over numbers E.g: '123456'

Comment: What if some of the numbers in the input array had more than one digit?

Comment: is it ok, if I add a very simple solution to this problem that I wrote ?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of a DFS could work for small enough input (which the problem's constraints might support) but I'm confused about why convert the number list to a string rather than just perform the DFS directly on the numbers. To find errors in your current method, I would recommend writing intermediate steps to the console to see if they are as you would expect.

Here's some accepted code with the idea of building the possible sums and counting the ways to reach them by including the ways we already have from previous iterations. Hopefully the code makes it clear.

```js
function f(nums, S){
  let sums = {0: 1}

  for (let i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
    let newSums = {}
    for (let [sum, ways] of Object.entries(sums)){
      if (nums[i] == 0){
        newSums[sum] = 2 * ways
        continue
      }
      added = Number(sum) + nums[i]
      subtracted = Number(sum) - nums[i]
      newSums[added] = ways + (newSums[added] || 0)
      newSums[subtracted] = ways + (newSums[subtracted] || 0)
    }
    sums = newSums
  }
  return sums[S] || 0
}

var A = [1, 0]
var target = 1
console.log(f(A, target))

A = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
target = 3
console.log(f(A, target))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, in your algorithm converting array to string is reduntant as you can directly work with 2nd step of your algorithm i.e dfs/recursion, just like this below (sorry, I don't know javascript but I hope it easier to read)

```
int find_it(vector<int> & a , int i , int n , int &sum , int sum_till_now)
{
    if(i == n)
    {
        if(sum_till_now == sum)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }
    int first = find_it(a , i + 1 , n , sum ,  sum_till_now - a[i]);
    first += find_it(a , i + 1 , n , sum , sum_till_now + a[i]);

    return first;
}
int findTargetSumWays(vector<int>& nums, int sum) {
    int n = nums.size();
    int ways = find_it(nums , 0 , n , sum , 0);
    return ways;  
}
```

but then if you think of optimization, then you will see that recursion/dfs tree is generating many repeated recursion functions, how do we avoid repeated recursion function, well dynamic programming can be used, if we know what are the states on which different recursion functions are formed, here those are i(current position) and sum_till_now(I mean we can different two recursion function in a recursion tree through these two parameters, so states in dynamic programming), so if we store those combination of state, it is equivalent to saving the function information, so next time we don't have to go again in the recursion tree of already visited/saved function. one thing, some people argue that this is not dynamic programming, it is dfs + memoisation, but again many other also argues that it is top-down dynamic programming as recursion also explore sub problems and then we save different states.

below is the optimized version:

```
vector<vector<int>>dp
int find_it(vector<int> & a , int i , int n , int &sum , int sum_till_now)
{
    if(i == n)
    {
        if(sum_till_now == sum)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }
    if(dp[i][sum_till_now + 1000] != -1)
        return dp[i][sum_till_now + 1000];

    int first = find_it(a , i + 1 , n , sum ,  sum_till_now - a[i]);
    first += find_it(a , i + 1 , n , sum , sum_till_now + a[i]);

    return dp[i][sum_till_now + 1000] = first;
}
int findTargetSumWays(vector<int>& nums, int sum) {
    int n = nums.size();
    dp = vector<vector<int>> (n, vector<int>(2001 , -1));
    int ways = find_it(nums , 0 , n , sum , 0);
    return ways;   
}
```

one thing, I have added 1000 in sum_till_now while using dp value or assigning value to dp because it is given that max sum can go upto 1000, so by symmetry it is clear that max sum in negative value can also only go upto -1000, so since array or vector index can't have negative index, so I have increased sum_till_now  by 1000 to make it non-negative.